# Is it possible to track new style RTs to an account I don't have access to?

Tags: twitter, retweet

If I have access to an account, I can use either `twitter.com/#!/retweeted_of_mine` or give `retweetrank.com/retweeted.in/etc` (read-only) access to see who has new style RT'ed the account.

Is it possible to see this info at all if I don't have access to the account?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a third party tool like [Favstar.fm](http://favstar.fm/)

Comment: Unless I am missing something, I can confirm that FavStar does NOT allow for it. Heck, it couldnt even find an user I know exists.

Comment: @Gaia hmm? [Pretty sure you can](http://favstar.fm/users/Jerwinsamuel/recent)

Comment: User has to sign in to FavStar, and I want to track "an account I don't have access to": 

"Stats can't be shown as @twitteruser has never signed in to Favstar."